# can you suggest me an emulator

Tags: windows-7

I have 2 gb ram, Intel core 2 duo processor,windows 7 starter, 32 bit OS and no graphic card. So how can I play PUBG game on my pc smoothly without lagging.I do not have Virtualization technology so tell an emulator which do no want VT.

Comment: Your PC is barely capable of playing solitaire. It is not adequate for a game like PUBG.

Comment: I want to play PUBG mobile game on pc with help of emulator.

Comment: That's not going to happen.

Comment: But I downloaded memu app player but the problem was that it was lagging as I don't have VT in my pc so I wanted an emulator which do not want VT

Comment: There is zero chance that you're going to play PUBG without lag on your current PC no matter which emulator you use. Your PC is simply not up to the task at hand.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the minimum systems requirements for PUBG from [PUBG PC system requirements: what you need for 60 fps](https://gamingrequirements.com/requires/pubg-pc-requirements/59480/)

> - OS: 64-bit Windows 7, Windows 8.1, Windows 10
> - Processor: Intel Core i3-4340 / AMD FX-6300
> - Memory: 6 GB RAM
> - Graphics: Nvidia GeForce GTX 660 2GB / AMD Radeon HD 7850 2GB
> - DirectX: Version 11
> - Network: Broadband Internet connection
> - Storage: 30 GB available space

As your system clearly does not meet them, you will not be able to play the game.